# How do I connect using ssh over a direct Ethernet connection?

Tags: ssh, freeze, ethernet, debugging

I have a laptop, a desktop, and a spare 5' Ethernet cable that I can use to directly connect one to the other. The desktop freezes every few days or so, seemingly at random, and when it happens I want to be able to `ssh` into it as mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze#Reporting_GPU_lockup_Bugs) so I can make a proper bug report and get this fixed.

Unfortunately, the linked guide doesn't give any instructions on how to do this. Can someone provide a step-by-step answer on how to `ssh` from my laptop into my desktop when the latter freezes, and also how to conveniently retrieve the necessary files once logged in to attach to the bug report?

A couple things to keep in mind:

- I'm using standard desktop Ubuntu installs on both systems. If there's any extra packages I need installed beforehand, let me know.
- My machines each have only a single Ethernet port; the desktop uses this for its wired-only Internet connection, and my laptop on the other hand uses an 802.11n WiFi connection. Only one machine can use the wired connection at a time due to network restrictions in my dorm, and the wireless connection my laptop uses is *very* unreliable. Thus, answers should preferably not depend on a working Internet connection, but rather a direct connection between the two machines, if that's possible.
- I've never logged into one of my own machines from another of my own before, so assume I know nothing and be sure to provide plenty of details. :)

Answer (score 4):

To establish basic network connectivity between two computers, it's much easier to connect computers using a SOHO network switch (something equivalent to, say, a Linksys SE1500) and then [assign static IP addresses](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-static-ip/) to each host. This is a more flexible and robust configuration than a direct link. Definitely worth the ~40 bucks.

If direct link is the only option, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543087 has details. The use of a cross-over cable may not be a hard requirement if both computers support [Auto-MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX).

[The SSH wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH) should tell you what you need to get SSH running on your desktop. Once you've got a SSH connection established, you can just copy the required files to a known location like your home directory with `cp`. Example:

```
cp /var/log/Xorg.0.log ~/
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to get around to this until today. I am unable to connect using that guide...when I hook up the two machines via my Ethernet cable, they try but fail to establish a wired connection, and as such I can't attempt to `ssh` from the laptop into the desktop. Can you edit your answer with the exact steps needed in order to get this working so it's [more helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259)? Thanks.

Comment: Woops, I missed the part about the link being direct. Updated. It seemed redundant to copy/paste the configuration steps from the Ubuntuforums thread, but if you think it's worth it, I can put them in.

Comment: The quick solution with Network Manager is explained better as a recipe over at [How to Set Up Ubuntu With a Crossover Cable](http://www.ehow.com/how_7193141_set-up-ubuntu-crossover-cable.html).